# Able to reach IP but not hostname (despite host resolution)

Tags: linux, dns, ping

When pinging a specific ip (intranet)

```
ping 10.14.5.10    
PING 10.14.5.10 (10.14.0.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.14.5.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.858 ms
64 bytes from 10.14.5.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.671 ms
^C
```

Testing forward AND reverse dns resolution **works**!

```
host 10.14.5.10 
10.14.5.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer some.intranet.url.
$ host some.intranet.url
some.intranet.url. has address 10.14.5.10
$ ping some.intranet.url
ping: unknown host some.intranet.url
```

**However**:

```
ping some.intranet.url
ping unknown host some.intranet.url
```

Why it is resolved, but unreachable?

Working on `Ubuntu 16.04.01` VM on `ESXI 6.0`

#### Configuration

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens160
iface ens160 inet static
    address 10.111.3.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.111.3.1
    dns-nameservers 10.111.3.1
    # dns-zone my.zone.local
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.111.3.1
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: The obvious question is what happens if you do `host some.intranet.url`. And just because reverse resolution works, doesn't mean that forward resolution has to work. So there's a bug in the DNS settings somewhere, either on the client, or on the DNS server.

Comment: @dirkt hi pls check my edit on both forward and reverse resolution working

Comment: Guess: `ping` uses a different method of name resolution (`host` always uses DNS lookup), because the resolver on the client is misconfigured. Check `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: @DanielB updates provided

Comment: Does your “intranet URL” perhaps end in `.local`?

Comment: yes it does ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.local` TLD is reserved for mDNS. Do not use it for anything else.

So why is it not working? In `nsswitch.conf`, you have the following line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

This means, to resolve a hostname, it will first query `/etc/hosts`, then mDNS and only after that DNS.

The key is `[NOTFOUND=return]`. The `mdns4_minimal` service will ignore anything *but* `.local` names, because it cannot resolve them anyway. However, if it isn’t able to resolve a `.local` name (`NOTFOUND`), the whole lookup process is terminated immediately (`return`).

You could also remove `[NOTFOUND=return]` and it will fall back to DNS. However, please just don’t use `.local`.

Also don’t use anything else (`.lan`, `.companyname` or whatever) but a domain you actually own. Everything is bound to fail in the future. The domain doesn’t need any publicly visible DNS records.

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the issue; my question now is why `mDNS` **failed** to find the particular host (isn't it supposed to be **able** to query / discover _also_ hostnames ending in **.local** ?)

Comment: mDNS is [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). It doesn’t query DNS servers. Unless a host advertises its name via mDNS, it cannot be found this way.